# ScrollView is not appearing in android app

Tags: android

I've gone through all the other answers and most of them didn't use `wrap_content` for the child `LinearLayout` but my case is different:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"-->
<!--              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"-->
<!--              android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--              android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--              android:orientation="vertical"-->
<!--              android:gravity="center"-->
<!--              tools:context=".MainActivity">-->
    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/Scroll"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LL2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:clickable="false" android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="Loading..."
    />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="Earnings:"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/User_earnings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="Loading..."
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>



    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogOut"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="Logout"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

<!--</LinearLayout>-->
```

**EDIT:**

The code is not fitting on screen in landscape mode, hence I'm using scroll view for that.
Based on the thoughtful comments and answers mentioned below, I've made the following changes to the code:

- Set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in `ScrollView`.
- Set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in the very first `LinearLayout`.
- Added ids for `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout`.
- Added `android:fillViewport="true"` in `ScrollView`.
- Made `ScrollView` the parent view.

Unfortunately , the problem still persists.

Comment: Set layout_height on the scrollview to "matchParent"

Comment: Hello @AleksG , I set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in `ScrollView` but the problem persists.

Comment: set the first LinearLayout height to wrap_content.               android:layout_height="match_parent" to               android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you are not setting
android:id="@+id/ViewID"
for both the Linearlayout and ScrollView in your xml code.

Comment: I tried that , still not working.

Comment: Are you using android studio?

Comment: Yes , I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your layout by adding a few more textviews. The given xml code may fit on the screen and therefore does not scroll.

Comment: The code isn't fitting in landscape mode , that's why I'm trying to use scroll view.

Comment: Try to give `android:fillViewport="true"` to your scrollview  
or make your scrollview as parent tag like  
`<Scrollview>`  
 `<LinearLayout>`  
        `**everything else**`  
    `</LinearLayout>`  
`</Scrollview>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! , I tried both. It didn't work.